# Angularjs: change the value of table cell when user hits enter

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

here is my table

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in results">
    <td>{{list.name}}</td>
    <td>{{list.id}}</td>
    <td ng-model="phone" contenteditable on-keydown="myFunction(results)" keys="[13]">
     {{list.phone}}
    </td>
```

User can edit phone number and hit enter. How can I update the value of list.phone to the new entered value?
So for example initially results is like below

```
[name:John, id:123, phone:123456],[]....
```

but when the user enter `7890123`
then the new results looks like this

```
[name:John, id:123, phone:7890123],[]...
```

How can I do this? here is my directive

EDIT:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('onKeydown', function() {
            return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                function applyKeydown() {
                  scope.$apply(attrs.onKeydown);
                };           
                var allowedKeys = scope.$eval(attrs.keys);
                elm.bind('keydown', function(evt) {
                    if (!allowedKeys || allowedKeys.length == 0) {
                        applyKeydown();
                    } else {
                        angular.forEach(allowedKeys, function(key) {
                            if (key == evt.which) {
                                applyKeydown();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly hooking your data to the form, try putting the data into an edit model and then applying it after the method call.

Here is an example, not specific to your case, but you can apply this method to your use case.
[Example on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cR6XSPDUvBZvfYE8iR9D?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that how can I call $scope... in my directive? I don't know how to do it? I added my directive